# Is it possible to use Azure Custom Vision in a VB project?

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-custom-vision

I'm trying to include CustomVision features in an existing VB.NET application. When I try to call any of the functions to create a project or add tags etc., I get the following HttpRequestException:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I've been able to successfully connect using a test project in C# so I know my keys and endpoints are correct. Is it possible to use Custom Vision with VB or is it just incompatible?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you can execute HTTP request from VB, there is no reason that it should not work.

The exception you are facing might be due to network configuration from where you are executing it. Can you add more details / a sample code to reproduce locally?